# Loop for odd number wont close

Tags: java, loops

When I enter an even number, the code works and asks for an odd number, but when I input an odd number, it never closes and carries on the sum for every odd number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OddSums {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an odd number");
        int oddSumMax = in.nextInt();
        int oddSum = 0;
        do {
            if (oddSumMax % 2 == 1) {
                for(int i=1; i<=oddSumMax; i++) {
                    if (i % 2 == 1){
                        oddSum = oddSum + i;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(oddSum);
            } else if(oddSumMax % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("This is even Please enter an odd number");
                oddSumMax = in.nextInt();
            }
        } while (oddSumMax % 2 == 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because your `oddSumMax` will never be even again. And as your logic is in a loop, and your condition will never be even again, it will loop forever. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the loops. One loop to ensure the user inputs an odd number and a second one to do the calculations.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int oddSumMax;
// Get user input
do {
    // TODO: handle case where user does not enter a number
    System.out.println("Enter an odd number");
    oddSumMax = in.nextInt();
} while (oddSumMax % 2 == 0);

// Calculate
int oddSum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= oddSumMax; i += 2) {
    oddSum += i;
}
System.out.println(oddSum);
```

Comment: yeah i got it now... just got confused with my logic.